# I am getting error in c++ 'PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am getting error saying 
\dll\dll.cpp|206|error: 'PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE' was not declared in this scope|
\dll\dll.cpp|208|error: 'pfnThreadRtn' was not declared in this scope|
|208|error: 'pfnThreadRtn' was not declared in this scope|

how can i fix

```
char CurPath[256];
strcpy(CurPath,dllpath);
int len = (strlen(CurPath)+1)*2;
WCHAR wCurPath[256];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,0,CurPath,-1,wCurPath,256);

pszLibFileRemote = (PWSTR)
    VirtualAllocEx(hRemoteProcess,NULL,len,MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_READWRITE);

WriteProcessMemory(hRemoteProcess,pszLibFileRemote,
                (PVOID)wCurPath,len,NULL);

PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pfnThreadRtn = (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)
    GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("Kernel32")), "LoadLibraryW");

hRemoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(hRemoteProcess,NULL,0,
    pfnThreadRtn,pszLibFileRemote,0,NULL);
```

Comment: Then you haven't included the header that defines that name.

Comment: Try `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` instead. There seems to be many errors in here.

Comment: Why do you use the C++ tag?

Comment: can you explain more i have     in top

#include "windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "YouHua.h"
#include <tlhelp32.h>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the typedef for a thread procedure is `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`.

In real code you also need to check for errors after each function call, a remote process can die at any time.